# Unknown error in a specific API call in Android via Volley

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-volley

My android app has been using Volley library for API calls. I'm making API calls to my own developed API which has been working fine. Today for a specific API call:

```
[GET] api.xxxxx.xxx/fetchdata/235
```

where 235 is the record_id in the sql db, I'm getting the following response for API calls made via Volley:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/lib/cat_jquery.js.jgz"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/detectmobilebrowser.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/redirectutil.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      <!-- fake for iphone internet detect -->
      <!-- <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML> -->
      var isToguide = isRestoreGuide();
      var wlanModel = getWlanModel();
      var firstLogin = isFirstLogin();
      window.location.href = Redirect(isToguide,wlanModel,firstLogin);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, if I hit the APIs directly via **postman client or browser**, it **works fine**. I have no idea why. Also api calls to any other record_id like

```
[GET] api.xxxxx.xxx/fetchdata/240
```

is giving me the normal response.

Android Volley code:

```
private void fetchDataAPIcall() {
    String url = Phantom.getApiURL() + "/fetchdata/" + record_id;
    String uri = Uri.parse(url)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("user_id", Phantom.getUserId())
                .build().toString();
    Log.i("[#]Request URI", uri);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    Log.i("[#]RESPONSE", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("[#]ERROR RESPONSE", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    });
    Phantom.getVolleyRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
}
```

What can be the potential cause of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: put android volley code here to better help

Comment: @BrunoFerreira- added